# how is this possible to be a phantom user?

Tags: support

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30163732/2307070) which have been written by a weird profile:

[image]

and

[image]

I reloaded the page twice, cleaned the cache and I still can't see who is the user.

Is this a bug or can we go in a kind of *anonymous mode*?

Comment: I raised this the other day on here, and everyone just linked old posts of other people then closed my question :)

Comment: @͏͏͏ that's annoying I can't ping you in the comments :/

Comment: @Thomas , Easy. Type `@`, press the TAB button and then a space, and then, type the comment. When you press tab, you'll notice that the "n more characters" below the text box changes. This indicates that the username has been copied in the textbox after the `@`.

Comment: @CoolGuy Wow it's funny :)

Comment: @ Thomas ,Like this: @͏͏͏ . Hey! I just pinged the _hollow-user_!

Comment: @CoolGuy Hate to be the bearer of bad news but that did not ping me

Comment: Well I don't ping you since I can't, but I'm happy with what you bring *hollow-user* (note that there is no way to me to know who you are, and this is frustrating.)

Comment: @͏͏͏  , Did this ping you then? If not, then this trick does not work... :(

Comment: @CoolGuy no sorry :(

Comment: Well in fact, I now know who you are :)

Comment: @Thomas Who am i ? + How did you find out ?

Comment: You're the guy that make me ask the question. Your profile link is in the code page

Comment: @͏͏͏Thomas , Me too. Found the profile page. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This user's username is "͏". That's `0xcd 0x8f` three times, which is the UTF-8 encoded character U+034F, COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER.

In other words, it's a username consisting only of non-printable characters. And a white avatar icon.

Arguably SO might want to filter such characters out as not allowed, but there's a ton of them and it's probably impractical to find every possible combination of invisible characters.

Comment: How can one find even this one in [the list of users](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2015-04-01)? Copy-pasting the character `[͏]` into the search box doesn't work, and neither does entering his URL-encoded *nom de prance*.

Comment: *Je ne sais pas* :)

Comment: This user is positively infatuated with his apparent superpower: see [the unlikely short comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30048340/2564301). As far as "a ton" goes, yes, this contains another: six times the `LANGUAGE TAG` U+E0001. ...how are we supposed to **@reply** to The Invisible Man?

Comment: @Jongware ‌‌:‌)

Comment: @Jongware ^ By which I mean to say: too short comments are easy... That guy isn't even very sophisticated. ;)

Comment: @Jongware And you can reply by using the offered @ auto-completion.

Comment: Yeah it looks weird but it still works. I left him a note to read this discussion. Maybe something good comes out of it.

Comment: lol ͏͏͏ ͏͏͏ ͏͏͏ ͏͏͏ ͏͏͏

Comment: +1 for filtering.  Do you have to find every combination of invisible characters?  Doesn't it work to simply disallow any invisible character?  This is *purely* a user's **visible** display name--not their login username.  Why would you need *any* **invisible** characters in a purely **visible** display name?

Comment: @nhgrif They are valid characters so you would have to find every one that didn't look visible, the computer doesn't care, it can't tell if they are visible or not.

Comment: Or just limit it to the 62 alphanumerics if people want to behave abusively with it...

Comment: @nhgrif Sorry, I can't take you seriously after the severe lack of understanding in your previous comment.

Comment: Lack of understanding of what?  I am a software developer... I know it's not as simple as just whether or not the character is visible... But there are a limited number of characters... It's a solvable issue.

Comment: @nhgrif SO has users with many different names from all over the Unicode spectrum. It'd be a real regression to limit that to just 62 alnums at this point. And with what justification? And what about all the non-English communities that SE supports now?

Comment: @nhgrif Then you just need to come up with a list... The COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER arguably does *something* in the right circumstancess, just not on its own. So... have fun. ;o)

Comment: @nhgrif  `limited number of characters` There are 109,384 code points since i last checked,so possibly more now. Good luck searching through them all to find if something looks visible.

Comment: Are you implying 109,384 and "limited" are different? Guess we took different math courses.

Comment: @nhgrif Are you saying that everything *< infinity* is doable...? ;-D

Comment: @nhgrif Probably took different English class as well. I never said there wasn't a limited amount, just pointing out how many there are.

Comment: It would be better to have a whitelist of characters than a blacklist

Comment: @Alvaro Either would be a pretty long list... :)

Comment: Stack Overflow only permits questions in English, why allow displaynames with characters in different alphabets? Something like `a-zA-Z0-9 \-\._` could be enough (making it mandatory at least one alphanumeric).

Comment: @Alvaro Again, there are many users with non-alnum names already. You'll at least want to include all the possible strokes and dots and slashes and hooks that all the European languages allow in their modified Latin script. Why not allow people to use their *actual* name? And while you're at it, why deny people from non-Latin-script-based cultures to use their actual name, even if they can otherwise write in English?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: because we don't require your *name* to be English. I'm lucky the Dutch settled on using the `i` and `j` combination for the [`IJ` digraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_%28digraph%29), but even in English it is not uncommon to have non-ASCII characters in your name.

Comment: I would also have taken that it was problem considering that the same DisplayName will be used in the different SE sites that may not be in English.

Answer (score 2):

That is [user/4453924/%CD%8F%CD%8F%CD%8F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4453924/%CD%8F%CD%8F%CD%8F). (And quite appropriately, "apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.")

The name is three times U+034F, the `COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER`, `cd 8f` in UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

This is why:

[image]

His name consist of non-printable characters.

Copy and paste the text from HTML and see what characters you'll get.

The [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4453924/%CD%8F%CD%8F%CD%8F) took "*apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.*" to the next level.

Comment: Doesn't my answer answer the question? :(

Comment: After your third edit it somewhat does. Before... not really.

Comment: @deceze I tried to better demonstrate the issue :)